# Query over Java Space connection?

Tags: java, javaspaces

Sample of the code:

```
    ServiceTemplate tmp1 = new ServiceTemplate(null, classes, null);

    try {

    /*      if(System.getSecurityManager() == null)

            System.setSecurityManager(new RMISecurityManager());*/

        thisIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        LookupLocator locator = new LookupLocator("jini://"+thisIp.getHostName().toString());
        ServiceRegistrar sr = locator.getRegistrar();
        JavaSpace space = (JavaSpace)sr.lookup(tmp1);
        System.out.println("Success");

    }
```

Encountering error at  [ ServiceRegistrar sr = locator.getRegistrar();]
which states

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:519)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:469)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:366)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:209)
at net.jini.core.discovery.LookupLocator.getRegistrar(LookupLocator.java:328)
at net.jini.core.discovery.LookupLocator.getRegistrar(LookupLocator.java:286)
at MessageEntry.main(MessageEntry.java:34)
```

I am new to JavaSpace tech, kindly assist me.

Thank You in Advance

Jeetesh.N

Comment: Did you started services? How you did that? From which source, from Apache River, Blitz, or Gigaspaces? Give more info about problem.

Comment: @Иван Бишевац: The code courtesy was from gigaspaces from http://www.gigaspaces.com/wiki/display/XAP7/Plain+JavaSpaces+Tutorial#PlainJavaSpacesTutorial-1.

Answer (score 2):

The `ConnectException` is a quite fundamental error which simply means that your Java process could not establish a socket connection to the target machine and port, because that machine wasn't accepting connections on the target port.  In this case it's almost certainly trying to connect to your `localhost` IP address using the default JINI port.

I'd suggest that this error means you don't have a JINI service/registrar running on your machine at the time you executed the code.